# Processing a HTML file using Python

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to remove all the tags in HTML file. For that I used re module of python.
For example, consider the line `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`.I want to retain only "Hello World!". In order to remove the tags, I used `re.sub('<.*>','',string)`.  For obvious reasons the result I get is an empty string (The regexp identifies the first and last angle brackets and removes everything in between). How could I get over this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the match non-greedy: `'<.*?>'`

You also need to be careful, HTML is a crafty beast, and can thwart your regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the HTML using BeautifulSoup, then only retrieve the text.

Comment: Is BeatifulSoup a module in python? or What is it?

Answer (score 1):

make it non-greedy: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy

off-topic: the approach that uses regular expressions is error prone. it cannot handle cases when angle brackets do not represent tags. I recommend http://lxml.de/

Answer (score 1):

Use a parser, either [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
import lxml.html
print lxml.html.fromstring(mystring).text_content()
```

Related questions:

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

[Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-lay)

Answer (score 0):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is great for parsing html!

You might not require it now, but it's worth learning to use it. Will help you in the future too.