# Processing HTML files Python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I dont know much about html...
How do you remove just text from the page?
For example if the html page reads as:

```
<meta name="title" content="How can I make money at home online? No gimmacks please? - Yahoo! Answers">
<title>How can I make money at home online? No gimmicks please? - Yahoo! Answers</title>
```

I just want to extract this.

```
How can I make money at home online? No gimmicks please? - Yahoo! Answers
```

I am using re function:

```
def striphtml(data):
  p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
  return p.sub(' ',data)
```

but still it's not doing what I intend it to do..?

The above function is called as:

```
for lines in filehandle.readlines():

        #k = str(section[6].strip())
        myFile.write(lines)

        lines = striphtml(lines)
        content.append(lines)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing HTML in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717541/parsing-html-in-python), [Processing a HTML file using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7694637)

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Regular expressions for HTML/XML parsing. Try http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ instead.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('Your resource<title>hi</title>')
soup.title.string # Your title string.
```

Comment: Update: try `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 2):

Use an html parser for that. One could be BeautifulSoup

To get text content of the page:

```
 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


 soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html)
 text_nodes = soup.findAll(text = True)
 retult = ' '.join(text_nodes)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually  use http://lxml.de/ for html parsing! it is really easy to use, and pretty much to get tags you can use xpath for it! which just make things easy as well as fast.

I have a example of use, in a script that I did to read a xml feed and count the words:

https://gist.github.com/1425228

Also you can find more examples in the documentation:
http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html